# How can i make a desktop shortcut to the game UT2004?

Tags: gnome, command-line, shortcuts

I want to make a shortcut on the desktop that will open the game `Unreal Tournament 2004`. Usually in terminal I type:

> sudo aoss ut2004

But when I make a shortcut and type the command in it, it doesn't open. What can I do in order to create a working shortcut? Also, I have `Ubuntu 12.4 LTS` if that helps.

Comment: Can you run the game without sudo? It is hanging while asking for your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe using `gksu` instead of `sudo` will solve your problem, create a new shortcut using this command:

```
gksu aoss ut2004
```

Comment: thank you so much it works, but my profile, and saved games are missing for some reason

Comment: about saved game did you try to find something like `.aoss` in your home folder. If you find that just move it to `/root/` folder and I think your saved game will stay @NickyBailuc

Comment: do you always use 'sudo' to run the game? doing so will run the game under the root user and it won't open the save games from your own user.

Answer (score 1):

## Make some file with extension `.desktop`

and write this in

> [Desktop Entry]
>     Name=Unreal Tournament 2004
>     Exec=gksudo aoss ut2004
>     Icon=(select an icon and write its path here)
>     Type=Application

then you need to write your password every time you run application but its OK.

## Other way

We will make script and make `.desktop` file to that file, don't know will this work or no but give try.
Make file called for example `aoss`
and write this in:

> #!/bin/bash
>      gksudo aoss ut2004

save file than open terminal and type thins command in

> chmod +x aoss

and than look at `how to create .desktop file` and create `.desktop` file to that scrypt

Comment: its i got it working already, but thanks anyway